# Flutter - 'initialValue == null || controller == null': is not true

Tags: flutter

I have three widgets and they are all in separate files from the "main" of these three widgets, I need to pass the controller to the button and TextFormField, but I don't understand how to do it correctly and therefore this error crashes. I also use ChangeNotifeProvide in the "main" widget.

I tried passing it like this **controller: user. firstName** and taking it in a widget with a TextFormField like this **TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController(text: controller)** but the error was the same

"Main" widget:

```
class _EditDataPageState extends State<EditDataPage> {
  final nameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    nameController.dispose();
    sNameController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<UserState>(
      builder: (context, user, child) => SafeArea(
        top: false,
        left: false,
        right: false,
        bottom: false,
        child: Form(
               key: JosKeys.keyName,
               child: ListView(
               children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                  //color: Colors.red,
                    child: CustomFormTextField(
                      lengthLimiit: 16,
                      textContoller: nameController,
                      initialName:
                         ${context.select((UserState p) => p.firstName)}',
                         keyboadrd: TextInputType.text),
                      ),

                      SaveButton(
                        key: JosKeys.keyName,
                        typeProperty: 'name',
                        controller: nameController,
                      )
             ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Widget with TextFormField

```
class _CustomFormTextFieldState extends State<CustomFormTextField> {
  final String? initialName, typeValidate;
  final TextInputType keyboadrd;
  final TextEditingController textContoller;
  final int lenghtLimit;

  _CustomFormTextFieldState(this.initialName, this.typeValidate, this.keyboadrd,
      this.textContoller, this.lenghtLimit);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: textContoller,
      inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(lenghtLimit)],
      initialValue: this.initialName,
      keyboardType: keyboadrd,
      validator: _validate,
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white54)),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white54)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The button is for saving and I need the controller there to update the data

```
class SaveButton extends StatelessWidget {
  //Map<String, String> saveStateForm;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> key;
  final String typeProperty;
  final TextEditingController? controller, secondContoller;

  SaveButton(
      {required this.typeProperty,
      required this.key,
      required this.controller,
      @required this.secondContoller});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void onPress() {
      if (this.key.currentState!.validate()) {
        if (this.typeProperty == 'phone') {
          Provider.of<UserState>(context)
              .updatePhone(this.controller.toString());
        } else if (this.typeProperty == 'email') {
          Provider.of<UserState>(context)
              .updateEmail(this.controller.toString());
        } else if (this.typeProperty == 'name' ||
            this.typeProperty == 'sName') {
          Provider.of<UserState>(context)
              .updateFirstName(this.controller.toString());
          if (secondContoller != null) {
            Provider.of<UserState>(context)
                .updateSname(this.controller.toString());
          }
        } else
          print('TYPEPROPERTY ERROR');
      }
    }
```

Comment: you don't have to specify initialiValue and controller, you just need one of them

Comment: so try to remove initialvalue and use its value when you initilaz the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use initialValue and controller at the same time. So, a better way is to use controller because its constructor does provide you initial value that you can set.

Here is an example.

```
// In class level 
final controller = TextEditingController(text: "Your initial value");

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return TextFormField(
    controller: controller, 
    // ...
  );
}
```

In order to track the value entered by the user you can then use

```
controller.text
```